# How to Make TweenAnimationBuilder Repeatedly

Tags: flutter

I am using TweenAnimationBuilder for creating countdown timer, like code below:

**Without Controller**

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 15),
                      tween: Tween(begin: Duration(seconds: 15), end: Duration.zero),
                      onEnd: () {
                        print('test repeat');
                      },
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Duration value, Widget child) {
                        final int seconds = value.inSeconds % 60;
                        return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                            child: Text('$seconds',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30)));
                      }),
```

**With Controller**

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 15),
                      tween: Tween(begin: Duration(seconds: 15), end: Duration.zero).animate(_animationController)
                        ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
                          if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
                            _animationController.reverse();
                          }
                        }),
                      onEnd: () {
                        print('test repeat');
                      },
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Duration value, Widget child) {
                        final int seconds = value.inSeconds % 60;
                        return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                            child: Text('$seconds',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30)));
                      }),
```

Before I added the controller, the animation work finely but only run for once (I need to repeat this `TweenAnimationBuilder` widget).
When I added the controller I Got Warning like

```
The argument type 'Animation<Duration>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Tween<Duration>'.
```

So how to make `TweenAnimationBuilder` with the animation and call the function repeatedly?
or is there any other solution than using `TweenAnimationBuilder`?

Answer (score -1):

You can't add `animationController` in `TweenAnimationBuilder`

I think you can use this if you need only countdown timer repeatedly

```
 late Timer _timer;
  int _start = 15;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          _start = 15;
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    startTimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Timer")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text("$_start")],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where can I put and call the function when the duration is zero?

Comment: Check startTimer function
I added already when time will be 0 then i again add 15 in start time then it will countdown again.

So try with this whole code